# Yeoman generator-angular-fullstack enabling ssl

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to be able to run a SSL server using the generator-angular-fullstack https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack.

However when I look at all the examples for enabling SSL, when I comb through the code it doesn't seem to initialize the server the same way as the NodeJS documentation explains to:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Has anyone had any success in doing it? Outside of that this generator seems to be incredible and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code above is how you run your app on 443, using the key and cert you have specified above.  This should allow you to communicate with your app over HTTPS, assuming you have those keys (and of course you'll get warnings in the browser if they're self signed).

But yes, that works, and is how it's done.  I've found that most people like to keep the Node app running on HTTP and instead use a web server (such as [nginx](http://nginx.com/)) to deal with SSL.  The communication from the web server to the Node app is then over HTTP.  This helps keep the Node app easy to run in a development/test environment, and then in production you have the security of SSL.

Comment: Is that the recommended way of doing things?  I am relatively new to the deployment part of it, I guess my assumption i would deploy it with no web server in front of it (like nginx or apache) and just deploy node.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you can deploy and run your Node app without a fronting web server.  But adding the web server affords you some capabilities that are worthwhile, such as not having to deal with SSL within your codebase, and instead separating that out.  For example, if you check your code into GitHub it won't work unless someone sets up certs (if you enable SSL in your app).  Also, the web server can route traffic to multiple Node apps running on the same machine under different ports.

Comment: @user1200387 If you decide to use nginx, here's a gist that might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/dylants/8609050  It is an example nginx configuration file for routing to multiple Node applications, with nginx responsible for SSL.